# On submit, form is returning to send.php instead of contact.php so appears blank

Tags: php

I have looked through posts with similar questions but am so new to PHP I still can't seem to figure out how to fix my problem, so thank you for your patience!!

I did a tutorial on youtube to create my contact form, it works well (content transmits), however, once the submit button is hit a message is supposed to show up at the top of the page that says that the message was sent successfully or that something was wrong with the submission - instead it just goes to a blank page so people don't know if the form has gone through or not. I can see that once the submit is hit that the url is showing up as www.communicatingwell.com/send.php when it should be still on www.communicatingwell.com/contact.php but from what I can see under Location it is pointing to contact.php so I'm not sure where the error is.

I've been trying to sort this out for about a week now and feel stumped. Hoping somebody might be able to give me some suggestions. Thank you!!!!!!

The form is located here: http://www.communicatingwell.com/contact.php

From contact.php file:

```
<?
$s=$_GET['s'];
if($s="1")
{echo('<span class="success">Your email has been sent to our web team. Please allow a           24 hour response time </span>');}
else if($s="2")
{echo('<span class="fail">Sorry ! Your message has not been sent to our web team.     Please fill the form correctly and try again </span>');}
?>
```

As well as the css in my head section:

```
<style type="text/css">
.success {
color: #333300;
margin-left: 15px;
}
.fail {
color: #993300;
margin-left: 15px;
}
</style>
```

---

send.php file:

```
<?
$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$messages = $_POST['messages'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$security = $_POST['security'];

$to = "info@communicatingwell.com";
$subject = "New Contact Form Submission";
$message = "A visitor of communicatingwell.com has submitted the following information.\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessages: $messages\n\nCity: $city\n\nComments: $comments\n\nPlease respond to this enquiry within 48 hours";

if($security=="10"){
mail($to,$subject,$message);
header("location:contact.php?s=1");
}
else{
header("location:contact.php?s=2");
}
?>
```

Comment: you've probably got an error in your `send.php` file which is killing execution before it reaches the `header` redirect. post the rest of your send.php code

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that this is throwing an error since `$security` needs to be assigned first. `$security = $_POST['security'];` at the top.

Something like this.

```
<?php 
  $security = $_POST['security'];
  if($security=="10"){
    mail($to,$subject,$message);
    header("location:contact.php?s=1");
  }
  else{
    header("location:contact.php?s=2");
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look at my code Enrique! I realized I should have included all the information in my send.php file as it was not showing the names I had already assigned. If you have any other thoughts, I would very much appreciate it!

Comment: Please, please, please! If anybody has some suggestions I would greatly appreciate it! Thank you!!!!